# How to check if string contains part of string (not whole string) in PHP

Tags: php

I have problem with checking if part of string is containing other string but `strpos` and `stripos` are not working for me.

The case that I need to check if word **pris** is containing in string **-med prista-**

Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean like [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/22a188accbdee36ed72a8c2e3f422246fa5792b9)?

Comment: If `strpos` isn't working for checking the possible position of a substring in a string, it means you are doing something wrong, and should refer to the manual (and/or post the code that isn't working): https://www.php.net/strpos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$str = '-med prista-';
if (preg_match('/pris/', $str))
    echo 'OK';
else
    echo 'Not';
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 8 you have a new function called `str_contains()` created for this purpose:

```
if (str_contains('-med prista-', 'pris')) {
    echo "Found!";
}
```

If you are using older PHP versions then you can use [mb_strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos) (multibyte), or [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos) functions like this:

```
if(mb_strpos('-med prista-', 'pris') === false){
    // not found
} else {
    echo "Found!";
}
```